# Log to record activity against a database

Tags: mysql

I've been assigned to create a general log.

I need a log that captures what actions were taken, by whom, to the database. Regardless of whether it is a `SELECT` or an `ALTER` or etc.  We need to keep track of everything that users have been doing to the database.

I have already created a general log to my localhost as a "mouse lab".  However, there are no records inserted into the general log table.

What can you suggest I do?  I'm using MySQL.

I'm losing myself on this, and I have no idea what to do anymore.  I'm just a freshie, not even graduated.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable general log by adding this line in my.cnf/my.ini file:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log

`[mysqld]`
general_log=1
also You can set `General log` output by changing your my.cnf/my.ini file (MySQL configuration file) to either TABLE or FILE if TABLE is choosen then server will log all queries in `general_log` table of `mysql` schema otherwise in FILE option it will log in a file path mentioned. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output